# Dataframe contourf plot Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with a lot of columns. I try to plot a contourf, but I have error like "Failed to convert value(s) to axis units".

```
x = np.arange(len(df.index))
y = np.arange(len(df.columns))
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

cs = ax.contourf(X,Y, df.values, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs)
plr.show()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you cannot plot all columns together, you probably need correlation plot?

Comment: I already have a correlation plot. And I could make smth like contourf in excel. I just try to plot it using Python.

Comment: can you include the example of plot you are looking for

Comment: It should look like this one. On left vertical axis I should have dates (df indexes). So I need to see the seasonality. (https://miro.medium.com/max/1112/1*hcMqwbSrcaxT_EOIUF3X8w.png)

Comment: @ JohanC I tried it. Doesn't work.

Comment: @user12628549 It would work in case your dataframe only consists of numeric values. To find out more, you'd need to share the exact error trace and more information about the values in your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns and rows are mixed up. You either need to use `x` for the columns and `y` for the index direction, or to transpose the values (`ax.contourf(X,Y, df.values.T, cmap='coolwarm')`).

Here is an example with toy data, and `x` and `y` interchanged:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 25))
x = np.arange(len(df.columns))
y = np.arange(len(df.index))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cs = ax.contourf(X, Y, df.values, cmap='coolwarm')
plt.colorbar(cs)
plt.show()
```

[image: example contourf plot]